# jquery - detecting if the bottom of the div is touching the bottom of the browser window?

Tags: jquery

Given a div on a page. how to detect when the div is scrolled to the position where it is at the bottom of the browser window... flush with the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: Can you post your html code or a link where we can see the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check

```
if (($("#yourdiv").offset().top + $("#yourdiv").height()) >= $(window).height()) {
}
```

The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the document. Contrast this with .position(), which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent.

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek5Gy/1/)

Comment: interesting but that always is true for some reason

Comment: I tried this to debug, the values never change: console.log( ($(".discussion-box").offset().top + $(".discussion-box").height()) + ' ' + $(window).height() );

Comment: In the demo try changing the top of `#div1`

Comment: what demo? not sure I'm following. sorry

Comment: Please visit the link I have shared in my answer.

Comment: interesting thanks for that but for some reaosn it's not working for me. maybe something else on my page is the problem. It's inside a div that is position:relative?

Comment: `The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the document. Contrast this with .position(), which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent.` From http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that it is not taking into account the position of the scroll bar, in the demo, it's static, it needs to notice where the scrollbar is right?

Comment: Can you post your html code or a link where we can see the issue?

Answer (score 19):

I don't think the above answer would work, since offset().top is the space between the div and the top of the document, and is not variable. This worked for me:

```
var a = $("#mydiv").offset().top;
var b = $("#mydiv").height();
var c = $(window).height();
var d = $(window).scrollTop();
if ((c+d)>(a+b)) {
  //bottom of #mydiv has just become visible
}
```