# Sticky Footer which docks on top of main footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which recognises when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page and docks the sticky footer on top of the main footer.

I'm looking for something like the footer of [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120215102345/http://be.blackberry.com/).

If this is possible in a few lines of jQuery that would be very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you. https://github.com/jami/Sticky-Attachment

Comment: Any examples of this? I don't have a git account in my office so I can't fork this

Comment: You don't need git to download code from gihub. There's a Download link on the right corner that points to: https://github.com/jami/Sticky-Attachment/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheap, quick solution to a question long since asked..

**code**

```js
var footerstickyHeight = $('.footer-sticky').height();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var footerToTop = $('.footer').offset().top;
  var triggerAt = footerToTop + footerstickyHeight;
  var windowToTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windowToTop + windowHeight > triggerAt) {
    $('.footer-sticky').removeClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.footer-sticky').addClass('fixed');
  }
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
}
.header {
  height: 111px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.main {
  height: 888px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.footer {
  background-color: dimgray;
}
.footer-sticky {
  height: 33px;
  background-color: dimgray;
}
.footer-sticky.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
.footer-more {
  height: 66px;
  background-color: dimgray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main">Content</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-sticky fixed">sticky footer</div>
  <div class="footer-more">more information</div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ztox79sd/

**credit**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675351/3377049