# how to stick an element to the bottom once the bottom is in view

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

How would I stick an element to the bottom once its bottom is in view? If I make its position fixed or sticky, it sticks to the top of the page, creating a "jump" effect. I just want to scroll down to when the element's bottom is in view, then freeze it right there. I've tried using waypoints, but I'm not sure what to do:

```js
    $('.background')
       .waypoint(function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
        //???
      }
      else {
        
      }
       }, {
      offset: 'bottom-in-view'
       });
```

```css
    .background {
     width: 100%;
     height: 130vh;
     background-color: #eaf1f4;
    }
    .story {
     width: 50%;
     background: rgba(51,51,51,0);
     position: absolute;
     left:20px;
     top: 140%;
    }
    .story p {
     color: black;
     font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
     font-size: 100%;
     line-height: 110%;
     
    }
```

```html
    <div class="background" id="background">
     <img src="img/rogers_bg.jpg" style="float: right;"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="story" id="story">
      <p>Mr. Utterson the lawyer was a man of a rugged countenance, that was never lighted by a smile; cold, scanty and embarrassed in discourse; backward in sentiment; lean, long, dusty, dreary, and yet somehow lovable. At friendly meetings, and when the wine was to his taste, something eminently human beaconed from his eye; something indeed which never found its way into his talk, but which spoke not only in these silent symbols of the after-dinner face, but more often and loudly in the acts of his life. He was austere with himself; drank gin when he was alone, to mortify a taste for vintages; and though he enjoyed the theatre, had not crossed the doors of one for twenty years. But he had an approved tolerance for others; sometimes wondering, almost with envy, at the high pressure of spirits involved in their misdeeds; and in any extremity inclined to help rather than to reprove. `I incline to Cain's heresy,' he used to say quaintly: `I let my brother go to the devil in his own way. In this character it was frequently his fortune to be the last reputable acquaintance and the last good influence in the lives of down-going men. And to such as these, so long as they came about his chambers, he never marked a shade of change in his demeanour.
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: @LayraNMS possible duplicate. Please check. Also, it is better to use a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Does [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) work for you?  See this article: [CSS-Tricks: `position: sticky;`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/).

It sounds like what you are looking for:

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
>   containing block crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is
>   treated as fixed.

You don't actually have to be sticky to the top of the container, you can stick to the bottom too.  See the following example:

```css
section{
position: relative;
}
h2 {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <h2>Hello 1</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <h2>Hello 2</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <h2>Hello 3</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <h2>Hello 4</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this turned out to be simpler than I thought. I thought that fixed positioning only stuck things to the top. Apparently, that's changed. Now you can stick things to the bottom:

```
$('.background')
      .waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.background').css({'position': 'fixed', 'bottom':'0'});
        }
        else {

        }
      }, {
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the errors provided in the snippet. You have to fix the javascript section:

```
$('.background')
      .waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
          //???
        }
        else {

        }
      }, {
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
      });
```

What kind of function do you want to use?

Generally, if you want to stick something to the bottom try this:

- Set the parent `div` to `position: relative`
- Set the inner `div` to: `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

That can be altered using the javascript depending on the view of the parent. This can help too: [jquery - detecting if the bottom of the div is touching the bottom of the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653911/jquery-detecting-if-the-bottom-of-the-div-is-touching-the-bottom-of-the-browse)

Answer (score 0):

I have something with vanilla JS. I modified your code to reference your background by ID instead of class and used [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect/) to determine when the bottom of the background is on the screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/cftf5h6L/

HTML

```
<div class="background" id="background">
</div>
<div class="story" id="story">
  <p>Mr. Utterson the lawyer was a man of a rugged countenance, that was never lighted by a smile; cold, scanty and embarrassed in discourse; backward in sentiment; lean, long, dusty, dreary, and yet somehow lovable. At friendly meetings, and when the wine was to his taste, something eminently human beaconed from his eye; something indeed which never found its way into his talk, but which spoke not only in these silent symbols of the after-dinner face, but more often and loudly in the acts of his life. He was austere with himself; drank gin when he was alone, to mortify a taste for vintages; and though he enjoyed the theatre, had not crossed the doors of one for twenty years. But he had an approved tolerance for others; sometimes wondering, almost with envy, at the high pressure of spirits involved in their misdeeds; and in any extremity inclined to help rather than to reprove. `I incline to Cain's heresy,' he used to say quaintly: `I let my brother go to the devil in his own way. In this character it was frequently his fortune to be the last reputable acquaintance and the last good influence in the lives of down-going men. And to such as these, so long as they came about his chambers, he never marked a shade of change in his demeanour.
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130vh;
  background-color: #eaf1f4;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
.story {
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(51,51,51,0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 140%;
}
.story p {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 110%;
}
```

JS

```
function ElemIsOnscreen(elem) {
  var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.bottom);
  return (
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  );
}
function AddFixed() {
  var bg = document.getElementById("background");
  if (ElemIsOnscreen(bg)) {
      bg.classList.add("fixed");
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", AddFixed);
```